# Programmatically changing SQL query and mapping, generating by JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My goal is to intercept "raw" SQL query, generated by JPA with Hibernate underneath it (this original request is quite complicated, generated through JPA criteria API and sometimes needs to be changed quickly, so I can't just move to native SQL), make some changes in it (changes that Hibernate is incapable to do, namely removing unnecessary columns in tables of connected entities), then executing it and mapping to the same entity structure original query is for.
My progress so far:

1. Got Hibernate query from JPA TypedQuery

```
org.hibernate.Query hquery = typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class);
```

2. Got native SQL from hql request (all necessary parameters for presented method could be extracted either from  hquery object of from entity manager):

```
private String hqlToSql (SessionFactory sessionFactory, String hqlQueryText, EntityGraphQueryHint egqh) {
    QueryTranslatorFactory qtf = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
    SessionFactoryImplementer sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementer) sessionFactory;
    QueryTranslator translator = qtf.createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, sfi, egqh);
    translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
    return translator.getSQLString();
}
```

3. Extracted map of query parameters from hquery, with names like "param0", "param1", etc.

My challenges at this point:

1. SQL string I extracted is exactly the same hibernate logging is outputting during execution of original query. It's good for logging, but not for actual execution - it has questionmarks (?) instead of parameters by names (like :param0) or order (like ?1). I would prefer to get actual query Hibernate generates, to not have to replace questionmarks within my code and worry about potential questionmarks in strings of generated JPA/Hibernate query. Is there any way to get SQL as it would go to JDBC for actual DB request?
2. I still need mapping of request results to entity structure. I can't just ask Hibernate to return entity this request is for, because fields aliases of generated query are quite different from entity field-to-table-column mapping. So, I need request results mapping either as object that native SQL JPA or Hibernate request will accept as mapping, or as function that will take list of raw query results and return list of entity objects. How I can get (more precisely, extract from Hibernate structures) such a request result mapping?

Comment: Look into entity graphs and named entity graphs. You can specify what it should load and specify subgraphs for your sub entities.

Comment: Entity graphs are already applied, they limit the entities to load, I need to limit the fields (and appropriate DB columns for those fields) of connected entities.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a DTO model and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A sample DTO model could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!